# Insert data to SQL Server Compact database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I work on a VB.NET project, and I have a button that I want to insert data to my table with. So this is the code of this button :

```
Public Class Form21
    Dim connexion As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=D:\Cours\Projets\Stge\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\datababse.sdf")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand
    Dim libelle As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim prix As Double = Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cmd.Connection = connexion

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Produit_fini values(@libelle,@prix)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@libelle", libelle)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prix", prix)
        connexion.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connexion.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem now, is that when I want to open the window where the button is figured, I get an error on this line :

```
Form21.ShowDialog()
```

The error says that I cannot open the window. Are there any errors in my button's code? Please help.

Thank you

Here is the error detail :

> L'exception System.InvalidOperationException n'a pas été gérée
>   Message=Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création du formulaire. Pour plus d'informations, consultez Exception.InnerException. L'erreur est : La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
>   Source=database
>   StackTrace:
>   à database.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create_*Instance*_[T](T Instance) dans 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:ligne 190
>   à database.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form21()
>   à database.Form1.إضافةمنتوججديدToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans D:\Cours\Projets\ferran\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:ligne 130
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>   à System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
>   à Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   à Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   à Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
>   à database.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) dans 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:ligne 81
>   à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>   à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>
> InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
>   Message=La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
>   Source=database
>   StackTrace:
>   à database.Form21..ctor() dans D:\Cours\Projets\Stge\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form21.vb:ligne 7

Comment: Your actual question does not appear to have anything to do with the title of your post. Are you having problems inserting data or with a dialog? And the code you have posted has nothing to do with the error you are asking about.

Comment: The windows cannot appear because there is errors on my button code. before putting the code, the window appear very well

Comment: Can you step through the code and tell us where the error occurs, and what is the error message?

Comment: What is the error? Have you single-stepped the code to see what is happening?

Comment: May be the query String is false or there is errors of syntax i don't know where is the problem. I get the error just in the line `Form21.ShowDialog()`

Comment: I edit the question and i added details of the error (sorry it's in frensh) @Tony

Comment: The stack track gives you the error: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet. Try to find which object has not been initialised on ligne 190.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form21

    Dim connexion As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source...")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand
    Dim libelle As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim prix As Double = Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
```

If these are form level declares as they appear to be you cannot reference controls (`TextBox1` and `TextBox2`) before they are initialized.   Change to:

```
    Dim libelle As String = ""
    Dim prix As Double =
```

Then in Form Load (when the TBs exist):

```
    libelle = TextBox1.Text
    prix = Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
```